# UIApplication fixed background fetch interval (private API welcome)

Tags: ios7, iphone-privateapi

I'm working on an internal app that requires to check the server every 10 mins or so when the application enters background. Normally, I can use APNS when new record arrives.

However, this app will completely skip Apple's garden, so **no** APN and **yes** private API.

So the question, is there any way for me to set the background fetch interval directly instead of calling the normal `application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:`

I also welcome other ideas for the same result.

Comment: How about VOIP background mode?

Comment: Nah, we didn't manage the server. And it's working against Lotus Notes, that's a different kind of hell. So far, I've tested with `UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum` and ignore `UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData`, I'm getting 15-20 mins interval.

Comment: VOIP is just hack you not need to do anything related, only add flag to plist and system will wake your app every 5-6 mins

Comment: o? I did not know that. I'll give it a go then. So just check the VOIP background mode, and it just works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend implement `VOIP` background mode, because is simply and provide app wakeup every few minutes. Just set `Voice over IP` in **Background Modes** and register handler;

Example:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler:^{
       NSLog(@"Here I do something every 600 seconds");
 }];
```

This method more preferable because can work on old iOS, and timeout is fixed vs background fetch where timeout is calculated by user activity and app usage.

Comment: Nice. As said, I didn't know that it doesn't require a server to make use the hack. Too bad it needs >=600 for the timeout.